# SSIS: Redirecting error rows to file. File contains additional unexpected carriage return

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I would like to redirect rows hat could not be loaded into a table to an error file.

[image]

I see that the red exception path has 3 Input columns coming in, the "Flat File Source Error Output Column" contains the original data in the file.

[image]

The problem is that when I open the file, there is an extra Carriage Return\Line Feed character after every row. I'd like to be able to manually fix the errors and reprocess them without having to delete all of the added CRLF chars. So I added a Script Component to shave of the characters being added.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{

    string buffer = GetString(Row.FlatFileSourceErrorOutputColumn.GetBlobData(0, (int)(Row.FlatFileSourceErrorOutputColumn.Length)));
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(buffer);       
    byte[] ThisBytes = GetBytes("Test");
    Row.FlatFileSourceErrorOutputColumn.ResetBlobData();
    Row.FlatFileSourceErrorOutputColumn.AddBlobData(ThisBytes);
    }

static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
{
    char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
    return new string(chars);
}
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

But my debug message box shows non displayable characters that appear as blocks.

[image]

When I try to force a literal "TEST" to the output file as a test to see if I could control what goes into the file, I get NULL (ASCII 0) characters after every letter.

[image]

Why is SSIS adding a CRLF when I just simply redirect the Output column to the file w/o using a Scripting block component to attempt to modify the data written? How can I get rid of the CRLF? Why am I unable to read the byte array in the data column and display it as a string? Why is the "TEST" literal having NULLS between every letter? Is my ByteArray conversion functions incorrect?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but what you are displaying is the redirection of rows that can't be read from the source file (Detail file). Just because they were read doesn't mean they won't blow up inserting into the table.

Comment: Yes, I am redirecting rows that can not be read based upon an expected set of column definitions that match the destination table. For example, col A from the file maps to Col A of the dest table. Col A in both places is defined as varch(1). If I get a varchar vaclue greater than len 1, I want it directed to the exception file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    string buffer = GetString(Row.FlatFileSourceErrorOutputColumn.GetBlobData(0, (int)(Row.FlatFileSourceErrorOutputColumn.Length - 2)));
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(buffer);
    byte[] ThisBytes = GetBytes(buffer);
    Row.FlatFileSourceErrorOutputColumn.ResetBlobData();
    Row.FlatFileSourceErrorOutputColumn.AddBlobData(ThisBytes);
    }

static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
{
    System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
    return enc.GetString(bytes);

}
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
    return enc.GetBytes(str);
}
```

I would still like to know why SSIS is adding the CRLF!